# What tense is used in "how the hell else could he have been flying off to Asia"?

Tags: present-perfect, conditional-constructions

The source is from the the movie "My Dinner with Andre. The full sentence is "People have always known that he had some money somewhere, I mean, how the hell else could he have been flying off to Asia and so on?, and still have been supporting his family?"

This is not an unreal past conditional as the subject (Andre) did travel to Asia. I guess it's a "could" plus a present perfect continuous "have been flying off", but it violates the rule that "could" can only be followed by an infinitive verb.

Please advise.

Comment: Here, _how could he?_ means _how was it possible for him?_